# Does Worlklight Studio really supports Windows 8.1?

Tags: visual-studio, ibm-mobilefirst, windows-8.1, worklight-studio

I am working with Eclipse Kepler 4.3.2 and latest Worklight Studio downloaded and installed through Eclipse Marketplace (6.2.0.00-20140801-1709).

There are a lot of official IBM docs and web pages stating that WL 6.2 supports Win 8.1 hybrid store app development. At the same time, the IBM tutorials lead to complete the build cycle using MS Visual Studio 12 Express.

As long as I know, VS 12 targets Win 8 only, so VS 13 is needed to target Win 8.1 store apps.
So, after creating a new hybrid app, I add the Window 8 desktop and tablet environment (and the JSONStore optional feature also), then build that environment. At this point I use VS 2013 to open the .jsproj located in the windows8/native folder. VS 2013 notifies that the project must be retargeted from Windows 8 to Windows 8.1, then asks confirmation to make writable two read-only files: index.html and cordova.js. The reason for changing the content of these files during the migration from Win 8 to Win 8.1 is to change several references from "Microsoft.WINJS.1.0" to "Microsoft.WINJS.2.0".

At this point the Visual Studio project is fully functional, and also correctly runs on the Windows 8.1 tablet simulator. The noisy problem is that at every build of the windows8 environment Worklight regenerates index.html and cordova.js adding again the references to WinJS.1.0.

So, the question is: does the current Worlkight Studio version full supports Windows 8.1 development? Or, there is something wrong in my approach?

Comment: Can you give info as to what you are trying to achieve here? Are you trying to run a Windows 8 store app on Windows 8.1? If yes, the procedure is described in the link below:
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/worklightsmobileplayground/entry/ibm_worklight_and_microsoft_visual_studio_2013?lang=en.

 On the other hand if you are trying to develop Windows 8.1 store projects, that is not possible yet.

Comment: We are able successfully open Win8 env created in WL in VS2013 professional/Ultimate. It doesn't ask for re-target. Looks like you are using VS2013 Express and its asking for re-target and when you re-build it in Worklight studio it again overwriting the reference to WinJS1.0. Is that what is your problem Can you give info as to what you are trying to achieve here?. or  are you trying to develop Windows 8.1 store projects in specific.

Comment: Srik, thanks for your comment. I was trying to build and run a Windows 8.1 store app on Windows 8.1. From your comment I learned that this is not yet possible (anyway, at this time I can't read from the link you point to because the blog page on developerWorks seems to be down; I will try later). So, your comment is a full answer to my question. I also understand (please correct me if I am wrong) that Visual Studio 2013 Professional is able to target both  8 and 8.1 store apps, whereas 2013 Express can only target 8.1 store apps.

Comment: There are no side-effects or limitations in building a Windows 8 store app using Visual Studio 2012 that can be run on both Windows 8 and 8.1 devices. As a matter of fact, this is the recommended way as of yet!

Answer (score 0):

Worklight Studio is certified to work on Windows 8.1 using Visual Studio 2013.

From reading your question, and specificically this part:

> At this point the Visual Studio project is fully functional, and also
>   correctly runs on the Windows 8.1 tablet simulator. The noisy problem
>   is that at every build of the windows8 environment Worklight
>   regenerates index.html and cordova.js adding again the references to
>   WinJS.1.0.

What I think is going on here is this:
You are creating your project in Worklight Studio and then open it in VS13 which then asks to migrate WinJS 1.0 to 2.0 and everything is working for you.

What you then do is re-build your project in Worklight Studio which brings back WinJS 1.0 as well as index.html

1. If you do changes in Visual Studio but do not bring them back into Eclipse, then your changes from VS will be lost. That is expected, because you are working with 2 IDEs, so you need to make sure that you copy back your code.
2. The template for a Windows8 app from Worklight Studio seems to be generating WinJS 1.0 regardless of targetting VS12 or VS13

So the only issue here is 2 above. It is worth investigating and it will be.
As for a "workaround", as long as you properly manage your code in 1, 2 should not prevent anything as you will still be given the option in VS to migrate to WinJS 2.0; it's an annoynace, though.